# Merge Flux emissions with duplication?

Tags: project-reactor

I'm having a `Flux` that emits items:

```
data class Item(
  val isEgg: Boolean,
  val isBasket: Boolean
)
```

Consider 2 'baskets' and 4 'eggs' emissions. I would like to merge those emissions into two: each containing one 'basket' and 4 'eggs':

[image: Flux emissions and it's transformation]

Is someone aware of such transformation? Flux is finite and should not exceed 1K items.

EDIT:

What I achieved so far - I grouped emissions into `GroupedFlux`. Now I would need to combine `GroupedFlux` containing `Basket1`, `Basket2` with with second containing 'Eggs' in order to produce two baskets with "duplicated" eggs in each one.

```
    val flux = Flux.just("Egg1", "Egg2", "Basket1", "Egg3", "Egg4", "Basket2")

    val block = flux.groupBy {
        it.startsWith("Egg")
    }
```

Desired Flux: `Flux.just("Basket1(Egg1,Egg2, Egg3, Egg4)","Basket2(Egg1,Egg2, Egg3, Egg4)")`

Comment: I think you will need some extra data structures for this, outside the pipeline.

Comment: Do you mean that each basket combines with with every egg?

Comment: I mean that in each basket there would be all eggs from `Flux`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this result with `flatMap` and `reduce`:

```
void combine() {
  Flux<String> flux = 
    Flux.just("Egg1", "Egg2", "Basket1", "Egg3", "Egg4", "Basket2");
  Flux<String> eggs = flux.filter(str -> str.startsWith("Egg"));
  Flux<String> basketNames = flux.filter(str -> str.startsWith("Basket"));
  basketNames.flatMap(basketName -> eggs.reduce(
      new Basket(basketName),
      (basket, egg) -> {
        basket.add(egg);
        return basket;
      })
  );
}

class Basket {

  private final String name;
  private final List<String> eggs;

  Basket(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.eggs = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void add(String egg) {
    eggs.add(egg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. I would say that checkout the merge() and concat() operators. That should help.

Edit:
Based on the additional details provided, the question is now clear. 
One possible solution is given below:

```
@Test
public void testBasket() {

    Egg eggA = new Egg("A");
    Egg eggB = new Egg("B");
    Egg eggC = new Egg("C");
    Egg eggD = new Egg("D");

    Basket basket1 = new Basket("basket1");
    Basket basket2 = new Basket("basket2");

    Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
    Sorter updatedSorter = Flux .just((Item) basket1, (Item) basket2, (Item) eggA, (Item) eggB, (Item) eggC,
            (Item) eggD)
                                .map(sorter::add)
                                .blockLast();

    updatedSorter.process();

    Flux<Basket> fluxBasket = Flux.fromStream(sorter.baskets.stream());

    fluxBasket.subscribe(d -> System.out.println("data:" + d));

}

class Sorter {
    List<Egg> eggs = new ArrayList<Egg>();
    List<Basket> baskets = new ArrayList<Basket>();

    public Sorter add(Item item) {
        if (item.isBasket)
            baskets.add((Basket) item);
        else
            eggs.add((Egg) item);

        return this;
    }

    public Sorter process() {
        System.out.println("---- Processing Eggs ----");

        for (Basket basket : baskets) {
            basket.addEggs(eggs);
        }

        System.out.println("---- Processing Done ----");

        System.out.println(this.toString());

        return this;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("(");
        for (Basket basket : baskets) {
            sb.append(basket.toString() + ",");
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        sb.append(")");
        return sb.toString();
    }

}

class Item {
    boolean isEgg;
    boolean isBasket;
}

class Basket extends Item {
    public Basket(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        isBasket = true;
    }

    String name;

    List<Egg> eggs = new ArrayList<Egg>();

    public void addEggs(List<Egg> eggs) {
        this.eggs = eggs;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(this.name);
        sb.append("(");
        for (Egg egg : eggs) {
            sb.append(egg.toString() + ",");
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        sb.append(")");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

class Egg extends Item {
    public Egg(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        isEgg = true;
    }

    String name;

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
---- Processing Eggs ----
---- Processing Done ----
(basket1(A,B,C,D),basket2(A,B,C,D))
data:basket1(A,B,C,D)
data:basket2(A,B,C,D)
```

Edit2:

Another solution, without a blocking call:

@Test
    public void testBasket() {

```
    Egg eggA = new Egg("A");
    Egg eggB = new Egg("B");
    Egg eggC = new Egg("C");
    Egg eggD = new Egg("D");

    Basket basket1 = new Basket("basket1");
    Basket basket2 = new Basket("basket2");

    Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
    Mono<Sorter> bucketsMono = Flux .just((Item) basket1, (Item) basket2, (Item) eggA, (Item) eggB, (Item) eggC,
            (Item) eggD)
                                    .map(sorter::add)
                                    .reduce((sorter1, sorter2) -> sorter.process());

    bucketsMono.subscribe(d -> System.out.println("data:" + d));


}
```

Output:

```
(basket1),basket2))
---- Processing Eggs ----
---- Processing Done ----
(basket1(A),basket2(A))
---- Processing Eggs ----
---- Processing Done ----
(basket1(A,B),basket2(A,B))
---- Processing Eggs ----
---- Processing Done ----
(basket1(A,B,C),basket2(A,B,C))
---- Processing Eggs ----
---- Processing Done ----
(basket1(A,B,C,D),basket2(A,B,C,D))
data:(basket1(A,B,C,D),basket2(A,B,C,D))
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer with some sample code I've produced so far.

Comment: @pixel Sorry for the delay... I understand your question now... there is no out of the box operator that I can suggest as of now.. but I have given a custom solution.